# How can I change the Profile Picture on my VS Code Line Blame Annotation

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

[image: refrence image]

I've been seeing this image popping up on muy VS code but it doesnt look the same with my git hub profile picture, infact i dont know where they got the picture from, its just an old picture of mine of over 7 years ago, please is there any way you can help?

Comment: please give a link the extension's marketplace page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe that thumbnail is using gravatar.

Log in gravatar.com. You can manage your pictures.